# jQuery datepicker not showing in dynamically generated input fields in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two input fields, one is directly coded inside html page and other is appending through JavaScript, and I have initialized jQuery datepicker for both fields with different id's.

I'm using jQuery ui datepicker

one input field in html page

```
<input id="datepicker1" name="" type="text" value=""class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

other in appending through javascript code

```
   var datepicker2 = '<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Cheque Date</label><div class="controls"> <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="datepicker2" name="" type="text" onkeyup="" class="form-control"> </div> </div>'
   $("#drop1").html(datepicker2); 


  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();

  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
```

Problem is the datepicker is showing with static input field in html page and not showing in dynamic field while appending through JavaScript.

Is it possible to intialize datepicker for dynamically generated fields?

Comment: Wrap the code that initiate datepicker inside `$(document).ready()`. The issue is you are trying to access an element before its rendered.

Comment: these fields were showing in a modal(popup window).

Comment: Use `.datepicker( "refresh" )` maybe solve your problem.

Comment: Issue is when the `.datepicker()` was called, the element was not rendered. Check if the element exists and then initialize it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you never add datepicker2 to the document. If this is the case you have to call something like this

```
$('body').append(datepicker2);//You may replace 'body' with '#drop2' or whatever is your container
```

before

```
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
```

See: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/xOqyQm

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code.

Add a common class `.date_picker` to input field and add the following javascript

```
$('body').on("click", ".date_picker", function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

Comment: You are creating the datepicker everytime a `.date_picker` is called. You should call it once only.